# Mobile Google Maps' setting for receiving location share notifications

Tags: 6.0-marshmallow, notifications, motorola-moto-g, google-maps

**tl;dr**: Is there any specific configuration switch or setting that controls whether mobile Google Maps is or isn't showing notifications about someone sharing a location with me?

---

I've been sharing location with my wife and friends and vice versa for past few months. Every time someone wanted to share location with me, I've been receiving two kinds of notifications -- regular email sent to my Gmail account and mobile Google Maps' notification. Tapping the other one always led directly to mobile Google Maps application with shared location shown in map's center.

Recently I have turned off many of Google Maps settings, privacy switches, I have disabled most of, if not all, of suggestion tips notifications etc. One of those turned off was most likely responsible for Google Maps's notifications, because I'm no longer receiving them.

Right now, if anyone shares a location with me, I'm only getting a regular email sent to my Gmail account. Because my mobile Gmails (actually PC's one also) has a regular lag of 5-50 minutes in receiving emails (since they're actually sent) such notifications are pretty useless for me.

I'd like to re-enable mobile Google Maps' based location share notifications, but I don't know exactly which configuration switch, option or parameter is responsible for them. Can anyone help here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all try clearing the cache of Google Maps application.

Secondly try changing the appropriate notification switch using the following steps:

- Open the Google Maps application
- Tap Menu Menu, go to  Settings >> Notifications >> People and places >> **location sharing** (get updates when people share with you on maps)
- Next to the notification (location sharing), turn on the switch (if enabled already, turn the slider off and then on).

Comment: The `location sharing` switch is exactly what I was looking for / what is the solution in this case. Thank you for a perfect answer.